# Run PHP In Safe Mode

Tags: php

Some time ago the PHP safe mode has been deprecated. That's why, I can't use it.

I'm planning to run a game server for a client who rents from me and I will give a `directory-FTP` to him. However , it'll run PHP and some plugins may use functions like `unlink()` outside of their allowed directory, being able to delete other dangerous server files... and functions such as `exec()` or any malicious, dangerous function should be disabled.

For example, [Hostinger's hosting](http://hostinger.com) has what I'm looking for. They limit actions you can do and don't let you go outside your allowed directory using PHP, and functions such as `exec()` are disabled.

How can I do that ?

Current Version : PHP7

Comment: ***Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.***

Comment: If your concern is regarding unlink and such outside certain paths you can just set user permissions to lock the scripts out.

Comment: What you need to do is make sure php is being run as a specific user, with only access to the directory for that user. Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: @nl-x I'm using Linux.

Comment: @KevinAndrews It's been a while that I've dont this in Linux. But iirc you should be able to configure somewhere in httpd.conf which user should be running the processes for what host. Then just make sure that user has (only) access to the directories/files needed.

Comment: @nl-x I'm newbie on this, can you tell me step-by-step ? Running Linux Ubuntu 16.04 TLS with SSH access.

Comment: im not the correct person to help. try migrating this question to the SuperUser SE communtiy or ServerFault SE